# Validate given coordinates in C,C++ or Objective C

Tags: c++, validation, expression, coordinates

I am trying to validate if some given coordinates(latitude,longitude) are valid. Is there any  function that do that or should I create my own regular expression??

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string? Or if not, what format is the data already in?

Comment: It will be string! It will be given by user

Comment: Latitude and longitude will fall into a small range of values. Validate them against that range and you have your own guaranteed legal range.

Comment: So you suggest to validate like this  -180 < lat < 180 and -90 < lon <90 ?

Comment: What do regexes have to do with coordinate validation?  There's two seperate things to do here: parse and validate.  Don't mash them in one step, it's hard and there's no reason for it.

Comment: Based on the comments and compulsive downvoting here, it seems the OP doesn't really understand the question he/she is asking

Answer (score 3):

There is no function like that present in C/C++. It's not that hard to figure out if they are or not.

Latitude and longitude are represented as degrees/minutes/seconds and preceded by a minus sign if south of the equator or west of the prime meridian. You can just check if the input that you have adhere's to these requirements. I am assuming that your input is three floats - degrees, minutes and seconds.

Degrees should be in the range of -90 to +90 for latitude and -180 to +180 for longitude. Minutes and Seconds should be greater than 0 and less than 60.

Here check this out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578799.aspx.

Comment: Can someone explain why I got a down vote for this. My explanation is quite clear.

Comment: You got vote down because your first answer was: "There is no function like that present in C/C++. It's not that hard to figure out if they are or not." which is useless. now I will remove it

Answer (score 0):

A coordinate is just a pair of floats, there is nothing special about it that you would need a regex for. You could do a reverse geo on the coordinates using google maps API and see if it resolves to a location.

Comment: It's about offline app. I want to valid the coordinates before trying to add the marker on the map

Comment: Why the down vote? You never explained this would be offline. Either way, quick research on latitude and longitude tells me that latitude can range from 90 to -90 and longitude can range from 180 to -180. No need for a function for such a simple operation.

Comment: I didnt vote down.. I know that is -180<lat<180 but it does not check that the given string is number

Comment: obj-c? just do
'    NSString *x = @"180";
    float y = [x floatValue];

Comment: I have 2 inputs. The user is gonna give me the values and I want to check that are valid coordinates.